# C conver unsigned char to HEX

Tags: c, hex, type-conversion, unsigned, unsigned-char

is convert unsigned char / int to hex, trouble is no correct translate ascci table:
original: 0D, converted: AD
code:

```
char int_to_hex(int d) {
   if (d < 0)  return -1;
   if (d > 16) return -1;
   if (d <= 9) return '0' + d;
   d -= 10;
   return (char)('A' + d);
}
void uint_to_hex(unsigned char in, char **out, int *olen) {
   int  i = 0;
   int  remain[2];
   int  result = (int)in;

   while (result) {
      remain[i++] = result % 16;
      result /= (int)16;
   }
   for (i = 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    char c = int_to_hex(remain[i]);
    if( (int)c == -1 ) { continue; }
    *((*out) + (*olen)) = (char)c; (*olen)++;
   }
}
```

where is incorrect ?..

Comment: That `out` is rather strange, you should probably show how you call this, too. Also, why not use e.g. `snprintf()` to do this?

Comment: what is the error case?

Comment: Probably bad caller.

Comment: I think it should be `d >= 16`. And then you seem to have a problem with the concept of casts. All of them here are completely superfluous.

Comment: Senks for all, solved:  if(d >= '0' && d <= '9') { return d-'0'; }
return d-'A'+10; in int_to_hex

Answer (score 1):

First of all one hex digit will cover values from 0 (0) to 15 (F) not from 0 to 16 (as you seem to assume in `int_to_hex` function).
Also you don't really need typecasting to `char` in last return of that function.
In fact all typecasts here are rather unnecessary
And typecasting of literal `16` is purely absurd...

And how sample input for `uint_to_hex` is looking ? You are aware, that on input (`in`) you can pass only single `char`acter ?

I think that char pointer would suffice for `out` - i mean, you want to return array, right ? 
So instead of `**` should be only singe `*`.
And I don't understand why `olen` has to be pointer (and argument to function too).

And you should try to write more concise and readable code, it will help you understand what you are doing too.

Comment: Yes, in - pass only single char